# Cheap/free parking near Frankfurt-Hahn Airport

Tags: budget, germany, automobiles, hhn

The official [low-cost parking](http://www.hahn-airport.de/Default.aspx?menu=parking&cc=en) near Frankfurt-Hahn airport is not really low cost with prices starting at 3.50 EUR/day. I will fly to Scotland for a week and now I'm looking for an alternative cheap/free parking lot near the airport. Are there any parking lots within walking distance or with an airport transfer?

Comment: EUR 3.50 per day sounds pretty cheap to me!

Comment: 3 years ago it was only 2 EUR/day. Yes it's not very expensive, but I hope that there are cheaper parkings

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found a [list with some private parkings](http://www.billig-am-flughafen-parken.de/airport/HHN) near the airport. The best options are:

- [hahn-parking.de](http://www.hahn-parken.de/index.php?id=1&lng=en) It costs only 2 EUR/day. There is no free transfer however it's only 2km from the airport. Taxi would costs about 7 EUR. No reservation required.
  **EDIT:** The link is broken, but the parking exists. The parking is on the [Shell station](http://tankstelle.bohr.de/kontakt.php) near the airport.
- [parken-am-hahn.de](http://www.parken-am-hahn.de/index.php?PageID=3) It costs 22 EUR for up to 10 days, when arriving at parking after 8 am. For arriving between 4 and 8 am it costs 32 EUR for up to 17 days. Free airport transfer for 4 persons. Reservation required.
- [airport-park-service.de](http://www.airport-park-service.de/) It costs for 8 days 24 EUR(with transfer) or 12 EUR(without transfer, walk distance about 3km)