# Cheap parking near YUL with free shuttle

Tags: budget, automobiles, yul

Parking at YUL airport or the nearby Econo-Park is quite expensive, from $25-30 CAD per day, which makes it not practical even for trips over 2 days, even by just an hour, since you get charged a full extra day. It used to be able to park in a lot nearby for $15/day and get a free return airport shuttle, but I could not find that parking anymore.

What is the cheapest parking option near Montreal airport including transport to and from the terminal?

Comment: Could you park elsewhere in the city and take the STM 747 or another bus?

Comment: It's basically the same as https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/14284/cheap-free-parking-near-frankfurt-hahn-airport but for a different airport and that question was protected! Definitely about travel too.

Comment: @choster - No, that would be too slow. I'm already in the city if I need to park at the airport :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Park 'N Fly](https://www.parknfly.ca/Location/Montreal-Airport-Parking.aspx) has rates of $15.95 for each 24 hour period, with shuttles

[Valair](https://onestopparking.com/Valar_Inc.Self_Park_YUL_100412?checkIn=) self park shows $10.99 Canadian per day, valet service $14.99 day