# How to find out the fair price for an elephant tour in India?

Tags: india, budget, nature-and-wildlife

As a foreigner it can sometimes be hard to judge what is a reasonable cost when the internet is flooded with ads directed at tourists (who are often willing to pay crazy prices due to lack of better knowledge).

Prices I have seen on the internet for 1 hour tours (2 people) literally ranged from $200 to $800. But what price would a local Indian resident expect to pay? If prices vary significantly by region, how can I get a rough estimate for whatever region I'm traveling in?

To prevent the question being opinion-based: I don't care about the "cheapest" option, nor do I care about a specific location or a specific cost. All I want to know is beyond what price is something exclusively geared towards tourists and should be ignored.

Comment: Feel extra free to edit or improve this question, as I had a hard time wording it in a way that could be objectively answered.

Comment: The thing is that prices are subject to change so this question is unlikely to be useful to anyone in a few months. I think as it stands the question falls into the [shopping](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/23/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) category and is therefore off topic.

Comment: @JoErNanO Imagine the question "Where in Europe can the cheapest alcohol be found?" is perfectly answerable. Sure, laws and cultures can change, but the general trend is that you want to be in Slavic countries. And it's safe to say that in no slavic country would a local pay more than 5 dollar for a normal beer. As far as I read on meta the goal is to block questions like "Where in Moscow can the cheapest beer be bought?" which is completely unanswerable, but general trends (you want to be in these and these Indian states) could be completely answerable. (cont.)

Comment: That's the thing to realize, Indian states are as big and populous as most European countries. This isn't asking about which park to go to or what the cheapest place is to get such a ride. It's about knowing which stuff is scamming users. Take Prague for example, there is a scam street stall on the old city center infamously selling pieces of low quality ham for swiss prices (some get a 50 euro bill for a single portion). Any local will know not to buy any food on the street above 8 euro EVER. Tourists however just have no idea what to expect and thus blindly buy stuff there.

Comment: Even looking at the linked meta post it talks about the type of questions which are hard to answer. And even aside of that, opening the [budget] tag there are mod-protected questions (posted after 2011 when that meta post was written) literally listing the cheapest parking places near a specific airport https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/14284/cheap-free-parking-near-frankfurt-hahn-airport . Not saying that's a good question, but at least I am somewhat skeptical of closing any question with any cost related advice. It seems more reasonable to judge the question on how answerable it is.

Comment: I've edited and reopened the question. I'll keep the old comments for now given the Meta question OP posted.

Comment: On a personal note - consider avoiding riding elephants in the first place. It's a cruel practice that I personally wouldn't support with my money.

Comment: @JonathanReez From the reading I have done my impression was that there is a big difference between the elephant rides you see around for example amber fort (carrying tourists up an hill all day) and the elephant rides you see in the nature parks ("just" an hour ride through the reserve). I personally don't consider a horse ride a cruel practice and elephants have been used as working animals since the bronze age as well. Just because it feels exotic to us doesn't make it intrinsically cruel (which is not to say a lot of options on offer aren't cruel). Price is just one consideration for me :)

Comment: Aren't all cases where elephant(s) are being offered for rides (for money) by people other than their handlers, by definition, for _tourists_? Are there any cases where elephant rides are available only for locals? And even if there are, then those locals are simply locally resident 'tourists". I live about 20 miles from a Kings Dominion park. They don't give me a discount because I am _local_ after all.  I'm not sure I actually understand what you are looking for.